# How to display customer name in woocommerce email template?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm new to Woocommerce, and I'm trying to show the name of the customer in the beginning of the email.

So the email will look something like this:

> [HEADER]You order has been placed [/HEADER]
>
> [H2]Hi {CUSTOMER_NAME}[/H2]
>
> [P]Some text[/P]
>
> [THE REST OF THE MAIL]

I've tried adding something like this to functions.php in my theme.

```
//add the first name of the person to the email. 
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_details','name_to_processing_customer_email', 10, 3);
function name_to_processing_customer_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    if( 'customer_processing_order' == $email->id ){

        // Set here as you want your custom content (for customers and email notification related to processing orders only)
        echo '<h2>Hej '.$order->billing_first_name .'</h2>';

    }

}
```

But this doesn't work.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this One ::

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_details','name_to_processing_customer_email', 10, 3);
function name_to_processing_customer_email( $order_id, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    echo '<h2>Hej '.$order->billing_first_name .' '.$order->billing_last_name.'</h2>';
}
```

Comment: It works. However the placement is not correct. The text appears just above the order-items, and I want to be just after the mail-header.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'name_to_processing_customer_email', 10, 2 );
function name_to_processing_customer_email( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
    echo '<p><h4>Shipping:</h4> ' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '</p>';
}
```

Check this WC3 snippet